# filter if date format contains string

Tags: c#

i have a date in the database with this format

```
2019-02-17 14:26:09.0600000
```

on the frontend table its being displayed like this

```
17-feb-2019
```

how can i query it so when i type "feb" the query will get all the data with feb on their start date?

this is my code so far. but the word its not fetching any data.

```
  var searchText = "feb 17";
  query = await baseQuery.Where(x => x.StartDate.Date.ToString().Contains(searchText.ToLower()))
```

Comment: Why are you storing dates in a database as strings? That's your first mistake

Comment: He isn't storing them in the database as strings, otherwise he wouldn't be able to do `x.StartDate.Date`. He's getting the user input as a string.

Comment: I think you need to flesh out your use case for allowing someone to enter text to match a date. Should a user that types "feb 17" find items whose date's string representation is "17-feb-2019"? What about "17-feb-2021"? What about "12-feb-2017"? Why is the user searching this way? Could their use case be handled better by allowing them to pick a specific date or date range? etc.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior yes. if year is not indicated it should find all feb 17 dates. i will update my question

Comment: @user10860402: What about dates that aren't Feb 17, but which are for February and have 17 in the year? What if you type "Ju 20": should it return items from June or July? What if the user is in a different language, where months have different names? And is that really what your users want/need? I'm trying to think of a case when I've ever been looking at data and thought, "Gee, I wish I could search for 'feb 17' and have it find every item that happened on a February 17th from any year." I can't think of any use case where that feature would handle things better than some other approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid trying to parse user-input strings as dates. The user will always find a way to enter a format that's either ambiguous or complete nonsense.

Ideally you use a `DateTimePicker` control (you haven't specified what UI framework, if any, you're using) which will allow them to select a date. Then you have access to a `DateTime` object which has lots of useful properties. For example, `.Month`.

So it would look something like this:

```cs
DateTime searchDate = DateTimePicker.Value;
query = await baseQuery.Where(x => x.StartDate.Month == searchDate.Month && x.StartDate.Year == searchDate.Year);
```

If you can't have a DateTimePicker and you really need to take user strings, you could do something like this:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Enter Date (e.g. 01-JAN-2021):");
string searchString = Console.ReadLine();

//Note, "dd-MMM-yyyy" could (and probably should) be replaced with an array of valid datetime formats that a user can enter
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(searchString.ToUpper(), "dd-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime outputDate))
{
    query = await baseQuery.Where(x => x.StartDate.Month == outputDate.Month && x.StartDate.Year == outputDate.Year);
}
else
{
//tell user invalid date format
}
```

Comment: You'll need to parse the Year, Month, and Day to an int to use it the way you're suggesting in your last code block.

Comment: thank you but month converts them from 1-12 though. and also I only have 1 search textbox.

Comment: I don't really understand your requirements, but the answer is that your user input needs to get converted into a `DateTime` object. However you do that is up to you. I've updated the answer with a neater solution.